# Return to beginning state at the end of the video

Tags: video.js

I'm using video.js (4.1.0), and would like to return to the ready-to-start state at the end of the video. I don't see how to do this.

If I do
myPlayer.on("ended", function(){
});

and load the poster frame in there, using myPlayer.posterImage.show(); it covers the entire video object, even if a user starts playing the video again.

If, at the end, I do this:
this.pause(); 
this.currentTime(0); 
it has the video paused at the beginning, rather than the ready state with poster frame.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

The poster image should disappear again when playback restarts - do you have a link where it does not? It does in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anUV6/1/), where the posterImage and bigPlayButton are shown and currentTime is set to 0.

```
var vid = videojs("myVideo");
vid.on("ended", function(){
  vid.posterImage.show();
  vid.bigPlayButton.show();
  vid.currentTime(0);
})
```